# Is ZLIB support in PHP enabled by default or NOT?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, zlib

In the documentation of phpmanual it says:

> Zlib support in PHP is not enabled by default. You will need to
>   configure PHP --with-zlib[=DIR]
>
> The Windows version of PHP has built-in support for this extension.
>   You do not need to load any additional extensions in order to use
>   these functions.

So as it says it should be enabled by default only in the Windows version of PHP.

But I install PHP and Apache on my linux machine from the repository, and then I noticed that it's already enabled. Used those commands:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5 php-pear
```

Does this mean that is also enabled by default if you install PHP from the repository?

Also I tried to install PHP from source code without adding `--with-zlib[=DIR]` configuration, just to check will `zlib` be supported or not. According to documentation on phpmanual it shouldn't.

I am not expert in compiling so I found tutorial for installing php from source code and I did next steps:

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev
apt-get install build-essential

wget http://in1.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.28.tar.bz
tar -xvjf php-5.3.28.tar.bz
cd php-5.3.28
./configure --prefix /usr/local/php5
------ I configure it without --with-zlib[=DIR]    ---------
make
make test
make install
```

and as last I run this line to have it work with apache:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

And after installing PHP on this way ZLIB support was again enabled by default.

If you are asking yourself how am I checking is it enabled or not, here is the answer.

I am checking it `phpinfo();` and it always says it is enabled:

[image]

And also I was checking for few function from this library:

```
if(function_exists('gzdeflate'))
{
    echo 'ZLIB is supported';
}
else
{
    echo 'ZLIB is not supported';
}
//the result is always 'ZLIB is supported'

if(function_exists('gzencode'))
{
   echo 'ZLIB is supported';
}
else
{
    echo 'ZLIB is not supported';
}
//the result is always 'ZLIB is supported'
```

I am asking this because I have wordpress plugin. So as plugin it will be installed on many different servers.
Now I want to start with using functions `gzinflate()` and `gzdeflate()` for one new feature. So I did research and some tests and was confused because documentation says it is not supported by default but when I install PHP on my server it is always supported by default.

I really need to use those functions but I don't want to use them if it will not be supported on at least 99% of customers servers.

So is documentation wrong or am I missing something. If I am missing something then can you help me with any alternative functions for compressing which will be supported on at least 99% of servers.

Comment: You can't guarantee that it will be there, no, but it's very common.  If you need it, you don't have a choice anyway, yeah?

Comment: It boils down to "enabled by default" is not the same as "always built in". In practice it's only going to be absent if `zlib.h` isn't available at compile time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This section of the documentation appears to be incorrect. As far as I can tell, the `zlib` extension has always* been enabled by default.

While it's possible that this extension is not loaded on some systems, this is extremely rare. You do not need to add workarounds for its absence — just state it as a requirement and move on.

*: That is, back to *at least* PHP 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced a scenario few days back where I generated the reverse issue as stated by you. The aws linux ami I was working with has a php installation without the zlib configured, due to which I was not getting the zlib package.

I have to re-install the php for the package I wanted i.e. --with-zlib[=DIR] (not recommended, but was a official approach I have to maintain)

So it's not always available by default.
Hope that helps.