# How To Hide Warning in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/alt/php55/usr/lib64/php/modules/zlib.so' -
>   /opt/alt/php55/usr/lib64/php/modules/zlib.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is ZLIB support in PHP enabled by default or NOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357984/is-zlib-support-in-php-enabled-by-default-or-not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```